# GitHub self-hosted action runner git LFS fails x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl-certificate, github-actions, git-lfs

I am trying to create a GitHub action that runs on a windows server self-hosted runner and I'm stuck on my checkout failing at the LFS download portion

I'm using

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    lfs: true
```

The checkout for the normal code works fine, but when it gets to the LFS download step I get a lot of messages complaining about x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

> LFS: Get "https://github-cloud.githubusercontent.com/alambic/details_changed_to_protect_the_innocent": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

The self-hosted runner is on a domain that is behind a firewall that interrogates https traffic and inserts its own certificate into the chain, so I'm guessing that the unknown authority is that certificate, but I don't know where that certificate needs to be trusted so that things work.

The certificate is trusted by the OS and is installed in the certificate store through a group policy, but it seems that git LFS is verifying the certificate chain separate from that and complains anyway because the certificate is unexpected.

A common solution I've seen floating around for things like this is just turn off SSL checking, but that feels like just a temporary hack and not a real solution. I would like for this to work with all security in place.

As an additional note, this is running on a server that is also running TeamCity, and the TeamCity GitHub config is able to clone repos with LFS from that same server, so these problems are just inside of the GitHub action runner environment that gets set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the firewall only inserts its certificate into https traffic, I was able to get things working using an ssh-key. I added the private key as a secret and the public key to the repo's deploy keys, and now everything is working as expected.

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    lfs: true
    ssh-key: ${{secrets.repo_ssh}}
```