# GitHub Actions Checkout Load Key Permission Denied

Tags: git, ssh, github-actions, checkout, network-service

I am trying to checkout a repo using an ssh key because https authentication fails due to our firewall settings [original question about getting https authentication working with a firewall that injects it's own certificate into the chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72050445/4708150)

I was able to get this working previously, but the service was running as an elevated user. We are setting up a new server, and I'm trying to get things running in a more standard way with everything running as the network service user as suggested by github-actions runners documentation.

It is failing on the checkout step

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        lfs: true
        ssh-key: ${{secrets.my_private_ssh_key}}
```

In the log it shows that it failed to load the key

```bash
Load key "C:\\actions-runner\\_work\\_temp/d872e64c-0228-457f-9bfa-f9c01b1818ec": Permission denied
  git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
  Error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've seen a lot of info on things related to git@github.com: Permission denied, but I haven't found a lot of information about permission being denied when it comes to loading the key.

The one thing I did find is that a Load Key Permission Denied error is typically because the user doesn't have read access to the ssh key?

If I'm understanding the checkout action correctly, it copies the ssh key to to `.ssh` folder of the user account so that it can use that SSH key.

For the NetworkService account that should be `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.ssh` if I go to that folder, the `.ssh` folder has been created, so it looks like at least an attempt was made to copy the SSH key into that folder, and I'm guessing the key is deleted out when the action is complete, so it may have been there and then deleted because the .ssh folder is empty.

Why would the network service account not have permissions for a file that it wrote out in the first place?
Or is it possibly some other permission that is failing?

Can the ssh-key option work with the network service account?

Or is it possible to specify to use SSH, but not pass in the key as a secret, and instead just have the private key stored on our self-hosted runner?

**Update:**

I found another warning in the cleanup step for `checkout@v3`:

```
Warning: Failed to remove SSH key 'C:\actions-runner\\_work\\_temp\264e2651-1faf-44c3-9fa5-16a842f0d2a4'
```

but in the original setup it appears that the ssh key is getting setup without warnings or errors

```
::save-state name=sshKeyPath::C:\actions-runner\\_work\\_temp\264e2651-1faf-44c3-9fa5-16a842f0d2a4
##[debug]Save intra-action state sshKeyPath = C:\actions-runner\\_work\\_temp\264e2651-1faf-44c3-9fa5-16a842f0d2a4
processed file: C:\actions-runner\\_work\\_temp\264e2651-1faf-44c3-9fa5-16a842f0d2a4
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Looking through the debug log of the checkout action, it looks like the SSH key is copied to a temp directory and then full permissions are given to the computer account `domain\computer-name$` and those steps appear to be finishing normally, so it's unclear why when the SSH key is attempted to be loaded that it fails because of permission denied.

Comment: I ended up removing SSH authentication, and used the default token authentication through https, and for whatever reason, it works for Windows Server 2022 where it failed on our Windows Server 2012R2 because of the certificate injection, but they are both behind the same firewall. Putting this here because it's not really an answer, but I just went a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.ssh
> ```

That would be typical of a service [running as "Local System Account"](https://serverfault.com/q/9325/783)

Considering such a service has [other paths](https://serverfault.com/a/869199/783) for its data, check if persisting the SSH key in `C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\.ssh` or `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.ssh` would help.

Meaning even if the key is deleted out when the action is complete, it might persists in (or be restored from) this other folders.

Comment: After doing some more tests, I found that the SSH key wasn't actually being copied to the user directory, and instead it gets copied to a temp directory in the `actions-runner` folder and permissions are given to the computer's account `domain\computer-name$` In the debug logs, it looks like everything is getting copied and assigned appropriately, but the loading of the key fails still.

Comment: @TJRockefeller Is is possible for your action to run with the same account as your own? (Instead of the local system account). Is it a Windows service?

Comment: On our Windows 2012R2 server that's how we were running it as a local user account made for running builds, and it may work that way on our new 2022 server, but after I found out that we could run the checkout action without SSH using automatically generated temporary personal access tokens using https, I don't really need to get the SSH solution working, but it is odd that it was failing.